# How to log the graph from fairseq to tensorboard

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard, fairseq

I got the impression from reading tutorials that this would be easy: slap in a call to `add_graph()`.

First tricky part was working out where to put it. I've gone with [fairseq_cli/train.py](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/master/fairseq_cli/train.py#L260) at the very top of the `enumerate()` loop in `train()`:

```
for i, samples in enumerate(progress):

    if i == 0:
        # Output graph for tensorboard
        writer = progress._writer("")  #The "" is tag
        writer.add_graph(trainer._model, samples)
        writer.flush()
```

I'm passing `--tensorboard-logdir mydir/` into the call to `fairseq-train`. That causes a `TensorboardProgressBarWrapper` wrapper around `SimpleProgressBar` (or whatever logging format you use), and so I'm trying to re-use the writer instance. (Maybe that is my mistake?)

I can get the model out of the `trainer` object, and the other thing we need for `add_graph` is some data, which is why I've put it in the above loop, so I can use `samples`.  I've also tried `samples[0]` with exactly the same error message.

Which is:

```
Tracer cannot infer type of ({'id': tensor([743216, 642485,  92182, 793806, 494734, 275334,  53282, 449572,   1758,
  ...
  20734, 469070, 678489, 473213]), 'nsentences': 832, 'ntokens': 29775, 'net_input': {'src_tokens': tensor([[  225,    30,   874,  ...,  1330,    84,     2],
  [  442,   734,  7473,  ...,    38,     5,     2],
  ...,
  [ 6238, 11411,   428,  ..., 10387,     5,     2]]), 'src_lengths': tensor([21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21,
  ...
  21, 21, 21, 21]), 'prev_output_tokens': tensor([[   2,   22,  133,  ..., 4445,   46,    1],
  ...,
  [   2,   22,   59,  ...,  112,    6,    1]])}, 'target': tensor([[ 22, 133, 203,  ...,  46,   2,   1],
  [132, 429,  40,  ...,  46,   2,   1],
  ...,
  [ 22,  59, 177,  ...,   6,   2,   1]])},)
:Dictionary inputs to traced functions must have consistent type. Found Tensor and int
Error occurs, No graph saved
```

I'm hoping someone might understand that error message better than me? Tips on better places to put the call to `add_graph()`, or better ways to approach this whole thing (getting a visual representation of my model), are also welcome. ([PyTorchViz](https://github.com/szagoruyko/pytorchviz) hasn't been updated for over 2 years, and apparently won't work with latest pytorch.)

Tensorboard logging of the training is working, by the way.

**ADDITIONAL**

I poked around some more, and found it is going to call `forward()` of my model, which (ignoring optional args), looks like:

```
def forward(self, src_tokens, src_lengths, prev_output_tokens):
```

so I tried manually creating empty data:

```
dummy_data = {'src_tokens':torch.zeros((1,256)),'src_lengths':torch.zeros((1,256)),'prev_output_tokens':torch.zeros((1,256))}
writer.add_graph(trainer._model,dummy_data,verbose=True)
```

That fails with:

```
TypeError: forward() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'src_lengths' and 'prev_output_tokens'
```

And if I use kwargs-style:

```
dummy_data = {'src_tokens':torch.zeros((1,256)),'src_lengths':torch.zeros((1,256)),'prev_output_tokens':torch.zeros((1,256))}
writer.add_graph(trainer._model,**dummy_data,verbose=True)
```

it fails with:

```
TypeError: add_graph() got an unexpected keyword argument 'src_tokens'
```

I'm starting to think this may be a limitation in `add_graph()` and it will only work with a simple `def forward(self, x):` ?